# CT error 2:-308 on Xcode's debugger console

Tags: iphone, debugging

I'm developing an iPhone application that uses compass and GPS.

I've had an interference with compass, and I see on debugger console the following error:
`CT error 2:-308`

I don't understand the error.

Any advice?